# Trying to put Bootstrap modal in a button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Is there a way I can use a button(input type="button") to show the Bootstrap modal. Basically the default is using anchor based on the documentation. I have tried experimenting but no luck.

I'm not sure if my coding is wrong or the Bootstrap modal can only be activated if it is an anchor tag. I have also tried googling or researching if anyone has created this kind of result.

Comment: What is the difference? it should work same, on click event should be bound to show the modal... nothing to do with anchor or button...

Answer (score 1):

This should work the same way as with an anchor tag.
The problem is, it's based on the href attribute, referring to the id of the modal window, and placing this attribute on a button might cause some html validation to go wonky.

If you don't care about that kind of stuff you can just replace your `a` tag with a `button` tag.

Edit: just noticed you were using an `input` element rather than a `button`. Either way, it should still work.

Edit2: Just verified if what I was saying wasn't total BS by looking at the bootstrap code (2.3.2), and found this snippet:

```
$(document).on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this)
      , href = $this.attr('href')
      , $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''))) //strip for ie7
      , option = $target.data('modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({ remote:!/#/.test(href) && href }, $target.data(), $this.data())

    e.preventDefault()

    $target
      .modal(option)
      .one('hide', function () {
        $this.focus()
      })
  })
```

Looking at this, the href attribute isn't required, and you can use `data-target` instead when working with inputs and buttons.

Comment: I also got the same idea that the "href" was needed in order to call the modal window. Right now i'm using a custom modal but let me see if i can use the an input in order to call the modal window.

Answer (score 1):

simply u can fire event on Button Click and call function "onclick=showModal()"

JS CODE

```
function showModal()
{

    $("#modal-window-id").modal("show");

}
```

Comment: How to close the modal window ?